# SQL: Add up all data within a row

Tags: mysql, database

I'm not sure how to explain this. What i'm trying to do is add up the integer within a row in a table. So the table might have...

```
Quantity
2
5
2
1
```

I know I can say...

```
SELECT COUNT(Quantity)
FROM Quantity;
```

and this will return 4. But...How do I add up the actual data? So 2 + 5 + 2 + 1 = 10?

Comment: Do some reading about aggregate functions

Comment: It would greatly help you if you found a SQL tutorial or book. Aggregation is usually covered not too far in to those tutorials or books.

Answer (score 1):

Is Quanity name of table or name of the field?
Anyhow, you might try this:

```
`SUM(QUANTITY)
FROM QUANITY`
```

Comment: Thanks, been working 11 hours and i'm just losing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Microsoft Excel, you can use a function called `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM SomeTable;
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4001/2); it can be a good idea to play around with something like SQLFiddle, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), etc. when trying to figure something out

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity)
FROM Quantity;
```